# Android dim screen after FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, android-activity, android-annotations, android-screen

I have Activity that is started from GCM with FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON

**Below** is the code snippet:-

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        addFlags();
    }

    private void addFlags() {
        //Screen On
        getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    private void clearFlags() {
        //Don't forget to clear the flags at some point in time.
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        if (!hasFocus) {
            clearFlags();
        }

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
```

After device wake up I want to schedule screen DIM (after 15 sec I use AA framework). I have try to clearFlags() after 15 sec but nothings changed.

```
@UiThread(delay = 15000)
        void dimDisplay() {
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.screenBrightness = 0.0f;// i needed to dim the display
                getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            }
        }
```

and after user touch screen screenBrightness=1

```
@Touch
    void container() {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.screenBrightness = 1f;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        }
    }
```

Do you know more clean solution of the problem.. this code DIM display only one time. And I want to avoid usage of deprecated PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK

```
/** @deprecated Most applications should use
     * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON} instead
     * of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform
     * as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static final int SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK = 0x00000006;
```

Comment: i guess you should post your whole activity code here when you are calling dimdisplay?

Comment: I have use AA framework (AndroidAnotations) http://androidannotations.org dimDisplay is calling in @AfterViews my whole activity content generated from AA code. Actually dimDisplay works but I want native android DIM and break it onClick on display.

Comment: I want after setting FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON to turn back Activity to DIM and lock screen after time (this time is setting in users Display settings) I think that this is default behavior of every Android activity.